# Where is the log of used commands in Linux?

Tags: shell, command-history, utilities

In Linux, generally we use a lot of commands and it is difficult to remember all of them.

```
 history
```

command provides the list of commands we used previously but its limit is less. New commands are overwritten on old commands then old commands are missing. I think somewhere the log of the commands is stored in the system.

Is that log available to open and read? If possible can we change the maximum size of log that it can handle?

Is the output of `history` command depends upon the login-user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file `~/.bash_history` saves the list of executed commands. At least in CentOS this file exists, I don't know if it exists in other distros.

Comment: In ubunutu file ~/.bash_history exists

Comment: @AbdulGafoor yes, but that's what you see when you run `history`. It will only have as many commands as those returned by `history`. To keep more, you need to set the variables I show in my answer.

Comment: This file also exists in Mac OSX. You can type vim ~/.bash_history to see the contents of the file under Mac.

Comment: It's the `HISTFILE` variable which sets the location history file, which by default (for bash) is ~/.bash_history

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution is to increase the number of commands saved and returned by `history`. If you use bash, add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE=999999
```

From `man bash`:

```
   HISTFILESIZE
          The maximum number of lines contained in the history file.  When
          this  variable  is  assigned  a value, the history file is trun‐
          cated, if necessary, to contain no  more  than  that  number  of
          lines  by removing the oldest entries.  The history file is also
          truncated to this size after writing it when a shell exits.   If
          the  value  is  0,  the  history file is truncated to zero size.
          Non-numeric values and numeric values  less  than  zero  inhibit
          truncation.   The  shell  sets the default value to the value of
          HISTSIZE after reading any startup files.
   HISTSIZE
          The number of commands to remember in the command  history  (see
          HISTORY  below).   If  the value is 0, commands are not saved in
          the history list.  Numeric values less than zero result in every
          command  being  saved  on  the history list (there is no limit).
          The shell sets the  default  value  to  500  after  reading  any
          startup files.
```

Comment: Is there any log file that linux maintains for commands ?

Comment: @gafoor yes, the history file I mention in my answer. Nothing else by default. If you set the variables I shows, you will keep a list of thousands of commands.

Comment: Is the output of history command depends upon the login-user?

Comment: @AbdulGafoor yes, each user has their own history file.

Comment: can `root user` see all the user's history ?

Comment: @AbdulGafoor yes, root can see everything that's not encrypted. Depending on your setup, other users can also see your history too. Basically, anyone who has read access to your `$HISTFILE` (`~/.bash_history`, by default) can see your history.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such log, at least not by default.

There are tools you can install, like `acct` ("GNU Accounting utilities for process and login accounting") which can keep track of all programs executed on the system.

`acct` is packaged for most (probably all except tiny-distros) linux distros.  The home page is at http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/

`acct` provides the following commands, `lastcomm` probably does what you're asking for:

> ac
>       prints statistics about users' connect time. ac can tell you how long a particular user or group of users were connected to your
>   system, printing totals by day or for all of the entries in the wtmp
>   file.
>
> accton
>       turns accounting on or off.
>
> lastcomm
>       lists the commands executed on the system, most recent first, showing the run state of each command. With last, you can search the
>   acct file for a particular user, terminal, or command.
>
> sa
>       summarizes the information in the acct file into the savacct and usracct file. It also generates reports about commands, giving the
>   number of invocations, cpu time used, average core usage, etc.
>
> dump-acct dump-utmp
>       display acct and utmp files in a human-readable format.

Comment: Upvote over the other answers simply for precision of answering the query of OP. There **is no such log** by default. The OP is incorrect that there is some other, special log. The default log OP mentions is the right one, OP simply needs to modify settings to match requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take a different approach to answering your question. While the `~/.bash_history` log does log commands, scripts, one-liners, etc. **the user has full control** over their history.

From a SA's point of view you probably do not want this, instead you may want to *audit* what is executed on the system?

How I do this is by using `auditd`; some example rules are below for `/etc/auditd/auditd.rules`:

`-w /sbin/mkfs -p x -k sbin_mkfs
-w /sbin/mke2fs -p x -k sbin_mke2fs
-w /sbin/mkswap -p x -k sbin_mkswap
-w /sbin/mkinitrd -p x -k sbin_mkinitrd
-w /sbin/modinfo -p x -k sbin_modinfo
-w /sbin/modprobe -p x -k sbin_modprobe`

`auditd` would then log to `/var/log/audit/` when any of the above commands are executed (`-p x`) and you can then view all commands that were executed on the system and by whom. It has a *buffer* that you specify its size with, can configure `auditd` to overwrite old logs, etc.

This seems to be what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you don't use `bash`, it *won't* be in `~/.bash_history`, but `~/.<shell name>_history`. For example, I use `zsh`, my log is in `~/.zsh_history`.