# Is there a command history file for non bash/terminal commands?

Tags: command-history

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the history of files & scripts executed with the mouse (double left click) and the time when it has been executed.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the log of used commands in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234731/where-is-the-log-of-used-commands-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fatrace -t -f O >> /var/log/filesopened.log
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what does the option `-f` do exaclty ? In the Man, this option doesn't appear. And I didn't find it on the Web